# list google apps accounts

Tags: android, accountmanager

How can I determine if a specific google account is a Google Apps account?

I have 2 accounts on my phone.

a normal Google acc and a Google Apps account

```
accountManager = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts();
for ( int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++ )
{
    Log.d(TAG, accounts[i].name + " - " + accounts[i].type);            
}
```

It prints "com.google" as type for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK `account.name` contains email, right?

Google account (aka gmail) email address contains `@gmail.com` or `@googlemail.com`. Google Apps account always have custom domains. This way you can distinguish them.

Answer (score 3):

I was wondering too, but determine based on @gmail.com or @googlemail.com as many suggested isn't accountable.  Through some entrances, users can actually register a Google Account using emails other than Gmail.  Try this sign-up entrance: https://accounts.google.com/newaccount?hl=en